# How to get static data in Room? Cannot access database on the main thread

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-viewmodel

I have to get some data from my DB which then will be casted to json, i have made two methods in my DAOs which returns the items i need like the following:

TestataDAO:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM testata WHERE id = :id")
fun selectTestata(id: Int): Testata
```

Then in my repository i set this:

```
@WorkerThread
fun selectTestata(idTestata: Int): Testata {
    return testataDAO.selectTestata(idTestata)
}
```

And in my viewModel like this:

```
fun selectTestata(idTestata: Int): Testata {
    return repository.selectTestata(idTestata)
}
```

The issue is that if i try to get that value i get the following error:

> Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially
> lock the UI for a long period of time.

So at this point i have to set my function as suspended in Repository and make it like coroutine in the ViewModel, but how can i return `Testata` from the coroutine?

Here is how it should be:

Repository:

```
@WorkerThread
suspend fun selectTestata(idTestata: Int): Testata {
    return testataDAO.selectTestata(idTestata)
}
```

ViewModel:

```
fun selectTestata(idTestata: Int): Testata = viewModelScope.launch{
    return repository.selectTestata(idTestata)
}
```

But here i get the error as i can't return Testata by using .launch...

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use it like below, call this method with in coroutine scope:

```
suspend fun selectTestata(idTestata: Int): Testata  = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
    repository.selectTestata(idTestata)
}
```

Comment: I was able to get the result by using runBlocking, is using withContext better for that?

Comment: I would prefer withContext() over runBlocking , because withContext() can be used in any coroutine context.